# A five month old answer, oddly, made it into the late-answer queue?

Tags: support

I've almost never seen an overwhelming review queue on this site. Mostly 0. Which means the posts are getting their due reviews.

But just now I got a review for a five month old post in the late-answer review queue.

How did it not land into the review queue for such a long time and/or kept silently there? I don't recall ever having skipped this review.

And review audit haven't been switched on for this site AFAIK which I think should be.

Comment: possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150080/132874